# Can I use the wire shown in the fluorescent light to power LED lights that are 110 V and a vent fan on the same switch

Tags: electrical

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZW92t.jpg)

In the ceiling, I have a fluorescent light I want to use the wire coming to the electric to the fluorescent light to power my vent, fan and LED light strips and take the fluorescent light out. I want to know is it a good idea to add an electrical outlet to that circuit to power the 110 V LED lights and have them on the same switch.

Comment: I tried to add a picture of the light switch. It’s just a typical light switch, black wire, white wire, and ground wire.

Comment: This information should be edited into your other question to reopen it, don't ask a new duplicate question.